# Spark Streaming - Parquet file upload to S3 error

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, apache-spark, spark-streaming, parquet

I'm completely new in Spark Streaming topic.
Via streaming application I'm creating Parquet files of size about 2,5MB and store them on S3/Local directory.

Method I'm using is as follow:

```
data.write.parquet(destination)
```

where "data" is a DataFrame

If destination is a local path, everything works like a charm but if only I send it to s3 with path like "s3n://bucket/directory/filename" I'm getting following exception:

```
    15/12/17 10:47:06 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-3,5,main]
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:977)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkAccessByFileMethods(DiskChecker.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirAccess(DiskChecker.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChanged(LocalDirAllocator.java:285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:344)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:198)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsOutputStream.newBackupFile(NativeS3FileSystem.java:263)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsOutputStream.<init>(NativeS3FileSystem.java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.create(NativeS3FileSystem.java:412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:908)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:889)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:786)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:176)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:160)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:289)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:262)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetRelation.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$$anon$3.newInstance(ParquetRelation.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Read from bucket operation works fine.
Despite the error there is sth stored on bucket. Like "directory&folder" and it creates folders for given path but in the end instead of file there is "filename&folder" file.

## Tech Details:#

- S3 Browser
- Windows 8.1
- IntelliJ CE 14.1.5
- Spark Streaming Application
- Spark 1.5 for Hadoop 2.6.0

Comment: Do you have `winutils.exe` in `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin%`? It may or may not be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in Hadoop libs. I had to rebuild winutils (winutils.exe) and native lib (hadoop.dll) with windows SDK 7 then I had to move it to `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin%` and add `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin%` to `Path` variable. Projects to rebuild can be found under `hadoop-2.7.1-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target`. For win utils I recommend to use windows optimized branch `http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-trunk-win/`